# Several connections using one device on Twilio

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I have implemented Cell to Browser calls and it works whenever it is one incoming call. I want to create a queue and talk with several incoming dialers. I am initializing new Twilio.Device and waiting for incoming calls:

```
    Twilio.Device.setup(token);

    Twilio.Device.ready((device) => {

    });

    Twilio.Device.error((error) => {

    });

    Twilio.Device.connect((conn) =>{

    });

    Twilio.Device.cancel((conn) => {


    });

    Twilio.Device.disconnect((conn) => {


    });

    Twilio.Device.incoming((conn) => {

        //answer 

    });
```

If I answer one of the incoming call then another one does not come to Twilio.Device.Incoming callback, if do not answer any then all of those goes fine to the queue. I want to answer one, then mute it and answer another one. Is it even possible? Anyone had issue like this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you are connected to one call with Twilio client, you cannot receive other incoming calls to that Twilio Client instance.

What you can do is build up a queueing system using TwiML [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) and either managing the queue yourself or implementing Twilio's [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter).

When a new call came in, you could notify your agent's interface and allow them to redirect an existing call to a holding queue and answer the new call, or just to leave the incoming call in the incoming queue and answer it later.

That's not much detail, but that's the approach you will want to take for building something like this.

Comment: Is using task router the only way or any changes? (Asking as this was written ~3 years back)

Comment: Hi can i make more than 1outbound call with twilio javascript client device at the same time if anyone of call answers destroy other connection instances?

Comment: @NNem that's not something I've tried, but I think you might be able to. These days you can create different instances of the Twilio Device too, so you can use different ones to create the outbound calls.